# addressing mode efficiency

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86, cpu, addressing-mode

Can someone tell me if 'immediate' adressing mode is more
efficient than addresing through [eax] or any other way.

Lets say that I have long function with some reads and 
some writes (say 5 reads, five writes) to some int value in memory

```
     mov some_addr, 12      //immediate adressing
     //other code
     mov eax, aome_addr
     //other code
     mov some_addr, eax    // and so on
```

versus

```
     mov eax, some_addr

     mov [eax], 12      // addressing thru [eax]
     //other code
     mov ebx, [eax]
     //other code
     mov [eax], ebx    // and so on
```

which one is faster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the register indirect access is slightly faster, but for sure it is shorter in its encoding, for example (warning — gas syntax)

```
67 89 18                   mov %ebx, (%eax)
67 8b 18                   mov (%eax), %ebx
```

vs.

```
89 1c 25 00 00 00 00       mov %ebx, some_addr
8b 1c 25 00 00 00 00       mov some_addr, %ebx
```

So it has some implications while loading the instr., the use of cache etc, so that it is probably a bit faster, but in a *long* function with *some* reads and writes — I don't think it of much importance...

(The zeros in the hex code are supposed to be filled in by the linker (just to have said this).)

[update date="2012-09-30 ~21h30 CEST":

I have run some tests and I really wonder what they revealed. So much that I didn't investigate further :-)

```
48 8D 04 25 00 00 00 00    leaq s_var,%rax
C7 00 CC BA ED FE          movl $0xfeedbacc,(%rax)
```

performs in most runs better than

```
C7 04 25 00 00 00 00 CC    movl $0xfeedbacc,s_var
BA ED FE
```

I'm really surprised, and now I'm wondering how Maratyszcza would explain this. I have an idea already, but I'm willing ... what the fun... no, seeing these (example) results

```
movl to s_var
All 000000000E95F890 244709520
Avg 00000000000000E9 233
Min 00000000000000C8 200
Max 0000000000276B22 2583330
leaq s_var, movl to (reg)
All 000000000BF77C80 200768640
Avg 00000000000000BF 191
Min 00000000000000AA 170
Max 00000000001755C0 1529280
```

might for sure be supportive for his statement that the instruction decoder takes a max of 8 bytes per cycle, but it doesn't show how many bytes are really decoded.

In the `leaq`/`movl` pair, each instruction is (incl. operands) less than 8 bytes, so it is likely the case that each instruction is dispatched within one cycle, while the single `movl` is to be divided into two. Still I'm convinced that it is not the decoder slowing things down, since even with the 11 byte `movl` its work is done after the third byte — then it just has to wait for the pipeline streaming in the address and the immediate, both of which need no decoding.

Since this is 64 bit mode code, I also tested with the 1 byte shorter rip-relative addressing — with (almost) the same result.

**Note**: These measurements might heavily depend on the (micro-) architecture which they are run on. The values above are given running the testing code on an Atom N450 (constant TSC, boot@1.6GHz, fixed at 1.0GHz during test run), which is unlikely to be representative for the whole x86(-64) platform.

**Note**: The measurements are taken at runtime, with no further analysis such as occurring task/context switches or other intervening interrupts!

/update]

Comment: In fact, the difference in encoding IS the reason why register access is faster. The microoperations are the same regardless of the addressing mode, but the lengthy directly-addressing-instructions easily stall the instruction decoder.

Comment: In your example above for the CPU decoder instruction with register addressing is three bytes long, and instruction with immediate address is 7 bytes long. On Intel Atom the decoder can decode only up to 8 bytes or 2 instructions per cycle, on Intel Nehalem and AMD Bulldozer - up to 16 bytes or 4 instructions. Note that typical instructions are 3-5 bytes long, so additional 4 bytes of immediate address come at the cost of not decoded instructions.

Comment: Allrite I can accept this answer as a sort otf "PROBABLY [eax] is faster" no one sure of it :/ - I also think possibly it can be true, though 'dirrect immediate' is logically simplest

Comment: Since `s_var` is a global, its address will be in the low32, so you could have used `mov $s_var, %eax` to get its address into a register with a 5-byte mov-immediate instead of an LEA.  (You need LEA for rip-relative addressing, though.)  Your results are only applicable to Atom, as you point out.  A long instruction with an immediate address might need multiple uop-cache entries on a SnB-family uarch, but it will still be one uop, vs. two uops for two-step method.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing using registers are fastest.

Please see [Register addressing mode vs Direct addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410584/register-addressing-mode-vs-direct-addressing-mode)